# Swift equivalent objective c code ActionStringDoneBlock

Tags: objective-c, delegates, swift

I'm new to XCode. I would like to convert below Objective-c code to Swift equivalent.

```
ActionStringDoneBlock done = ^(ActionSheetStringPicker *picker, NSInteger selectedIndex, id selectedValue) {
        if ([sender respondsToSelector:@selector(setText:)]) {
            [sender performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:selectedValue];
        }
    };
```

Below is my effort, but there is error on (id selectedValue) and sender.performSelector("setText:", withObject: selectedValue)

```
let done: ActionStringDoneBlock = {(picker: ActionSheetStringPicker!, selectedIndex: NSInteger!, selectedValue : AnyObject) in
        if(sender.respondsToSelector("setText:"))
        {
           sender.performSelector("setText:", withObject: selectedValue)
        }

    }
```

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may need to take a look on the _optional chaining_ here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html, that will help you to understand how you can convert such snippet from _Objc_ to _Swift_.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, you can take advantage of [**optional chaining**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html), as long as your `delegate` (a.k.a. `sender`) is an `@objc class`:

```
sender.setText?(selectedValue)
```

**Note:** You can't use `performSelector...` methods or `NSInvocation` class in Swift.

Comment: thanks for the answer... selectedValue is always nil...i have no idea why it is nil...can guide